# Making new alias for $ in jQuery — good or bad practice?

Tags: jquery

I decided to set alias for $, because dollar sign is hardly accessible on keyboard:

```
$(function(){
    var ff = $;
    ff('p').hide();
});
```

Now I use ff instead of $ everywhere. Is it considered good or bad practice?

Comment: It's ok to define an alias. Only the name confuses me. In the context of web design `ff` always means *Firefox* to me.

Comment: @Roland — ironically, the correct abbreviation for Firefox is [Fx](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=How+do+I+capitalize+Firefox%3F+How+do+I+abbreviate+it%3F).

Comment: The dollar sign is fairly accessible for me on the UK keyboard layout. Shift+4 isn't very difficult. What keyboard layout are you using?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no such thing as a correct abbreviation. As long as people understand you,... Fx for me is an abbrviation of 'effects'.

Comment: Thanks everyone for answering, I guess I gonna continue using ff and replace it for $ if I making script for other people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$` name is itself an alias, the jQuery function is really named `jQuery`, so you can use that instead:

```
jQuery('p').hide();
```

The `ready` event handler also has a parameter that you can use instead of copying the global jQuery reference:

```
jQuery(function(ff){

  // now ff is an alias for the jQuery function:

  ff('p').hide();

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, jQuery has a noConflict mode for scenarios where $ is not accessible. $ is actually already an alias for jQuery or window.jQuery, so in your code you should better set ff to window.jQuery or don't set an alias and use `jQuery.hide()` etc.

Answer (score 1):

`$` is a meaningless variable name, so using that is considered bad practise.

`ff` however, is equally meaningless, so it isn't much better (although it does have the advantage of not conflicting with other things that use `$`)

A function name should be meaningful. Unfortunately, the jQuery function is so overloaded that producing a meaningful name is … tricky. It isn't helped by having even more functions hanging off it (such as `.get`).

`jQuery` is as about a meaningful name as you are likely to get for it. You might consider `jq` if you want something short.

Comment: Reason I chose ff instead of jq or jQuery is that it can be written with left hand very fast.

Comment: Readable code is a greater virtue then code that you can type quickly.

Comment: @AntoxaGray: That's not a good reason for choosing a variable name. A reason maybe, but not a good one.

Answer (score 0):

If it's easier for you to type that (really?), then do it, but I would do a search-replace after the coding..